# UIButton does not work when hidden

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am hiding a UIButton underneath a UITextField. Normally, the UIButton responds just find. However, when I set it to hidden (or when I set alpha to 0), it stops working.

For context, I am including a hidden button under a UITextField because the clickable area to edit the textfield is small--I'd like the user to be able to click anywhere in the neighborhood of the uitextfield in order to make the text field become the first responder. Thus, the code for the button is:

```
- (IBAction)enterTextField:(id)sender {
    [nameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"Pressed");
}
```

However, this code does not get called when the button is hidden. Otherwise, it does get called.

Comment: If you hide something, it won't respond to interaction... because it's *hidden*.

Comment: A view that is hidden, or has `alpha` less than 0.01, is ignored when hit-testing.  This is documented in the *[UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)* under the `hitTest:forEvent:` method.

Comment: @P.Wright: since your question had obviously been answered you should select Matt's answer and close this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it a custom button with `UIButtonTypeCustom` or set the background to clearColor.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. The only other change I had to make was to prevent the button from appearing highlighted when I clicked it: 

invisibleButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=NO;

Comment: @P, you should accept Matt's answer since he solved your problem.